# tooltip to work for mouse hover and click both - ngbootstrap

Tags: javascript, tooltip, angular7, ng-bootstrap

I am using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/ and required to open tooltip on mouse over and also on click.

Basically, on mouse  hover text1 appears and on click tooltip text changes to text2. In examples I see only on one event ( either on click or hover).

best example is - https://pypi.org/project/nltk/ - same functionality I needed using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/.

Angular 7 is being used in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [context and manual triggers](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#tplwithcontext) functionality of `ngb-tooltip` to achieve this.

In your HTML, define the tooltip:

```
<ng-template #tipContent let-greeting="greeting">{{greeting}}</ng-template>
```

The above HTML will display the value of the variable `greeting` as the text in the tooltip.

Also define the button (or other HTML) element that you want the tooltip to appear on

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2"
  [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"
  triggers="manual"
  #t1="ngbTooltip"
  (mouseover)="openTooltip(t1, 'text 1')"
  (mouseout)="closeTooltip(t1)"
  (click)="openTooltip(t1, 'text 2')">
      Tooltip on top
</button>
```

This uses manual triggers, and you can bind to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to display the tooltip `text 1` on hovering over the button. The `click` binding will display the tooltip `text 2` when clicking on the button.

The `openTooltip` function is defined in the TypeScript file opens the tooltip passing in the text that was passed in as an argument to the method. The line `tooltip.close()` is required otherwise the clicking on the button to display the `text 2` tooltip will not work:

```
openTooltip(tooltip, greeting: string) {
  tooltip.close();
  tooltip.open({ greeting });
}
```

There's a working StackBlitz demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxmeft-lj5kd5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-basic.html).

The `closeTooltip` function simply closes the tooltip:

```
closeTooltip(tooltip) {
  tooltip.close();
}
```